# Iterating a Map - why are operations undefined?

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, collections

Regarding `Map.Entry`, the Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) states:

> A map entry (key-value pair). The `Map.entrySet` method returns a
> collection-view of the map, whose elements are of this class. The only
> way to obtain a reference to a map entry is from the iterator of this
> collection-view. These `Map.Entry` objects are valid only for the
> duration of the iteration; more formally, the behavior of a map entry
> is undefined if the backing map has been modified after the entry was
> returned by the iterator, except through the `setValue` operation on the
> map entry.

This suggests that iterating over a Map is read-only. If operations on Map objects (such as `put()` etc.) are undefined, how does one bulk-update entries in a Map?

Comment: "This suggests that iterating over a Map is read-only."? How so? Also, it's not that operations on the `Map` are undefined, the only thing that's undefined is how the `Map.Entry` acts *after* such a modification (which is just an extension of `Iterator` having undefined behaviour when the underlying collection is modified during its lifetime). So just like you shouldn't hold on to an `Iterator` for a long time, you also shouldn't hold on to a `Map.Entry` for basically the same reasons.

Comment: "*This suggests that iterating over a Map is read-only*" You can't iterate over a map. You can iterate over an entry set of a map. And it doesn't suggest that. You can modify the map while iterating the entry set, e.g. by calling `Map.Entry.setValue()`

Comment: "Why" is not a useful question to ask, especially about something that is undefined. Having the behaviour defined would make implementers responsible for implementing that defined behaviour, and no one likes more work they have to do :)

Comment: If "no one likes more work they have to do" isn't a satisfying answer to your question, please edit it to make it clear *what kind of* answer you are looking for here.

Comment: "how does one bulk-update entries in a Map?" Just *don't* modify the map while you are iterating over it? I'm not sure how iterating over the map is related to updating the entries. There is `putAll` and `replaceAll`, which are bulk operations.

Comment: I see. So this would be undefined? `for (Map.Entry<String, String> m: entries) {m.put("foo", "foo");}`

Whereas this wouldn't? `for (...) {myMap.put("foo", "foo");}` - assuming that `myMap` is a HashMap defined earlier. @JoachimSauer

Comment: does `Entry` has a `put()` methods? (first one should be a compile error) (second one is the undefined one [assuming a loop *over* `myMap`])

Comment: I admit, I am confused @user16320675

Comment: if you are looping a map and changing it (the map) - that *can* be undefined (if not using the iterator that is being used for looping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>(Map.of("a", "b"));
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: myMap.entrySet()) {
    entry.put("foo", "foo");
}
```

doesn't compile because `entry` is a `Map.Entry` and `Map.Entry` doesn't have a `put()` method.

---

The fragment

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>(Map.of("a", "b"));
for (Map.Entry<String, String> curEntry: myMap.entrySet()) {
    myMap.put("foo", "foo");
    // the behavior of curEntry is undefined after the preceding line
}
```

is the case the `Map.Entry` documentation mentions: `myMap` is modified while iterating over it. That means that according to the documentation the behavior of `curEntry` is undefined after the modifying line.

Please note that modifying the map while iterating over it **also** leads to [unspecified behavior for the iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--):

> If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own `remove` operation, or through the `setValue` operation on a map entry returned by the iterator) the results of the iteration are undefined.

---

The fragment

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>(Map.of("a", "b"));
Map<String, String> otherMap = new HashMap<>(Map.of("c", "d"));
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: myMap.entrySet()) {
    otherMap.put("foo", "foo");
}
```

is OK because this code modifies `otherMap` while iterating over `myMap`. Since these are two different `Map`s this is allowed.

---

Bulk-Updating a `Map` while iterating over it:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>(Map.of("a", 1));
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: myMap.entrySet()) {
    entry.setValue(m.getValue() + 1);
}
```

is OK, because this code uses the supported `Map.Entry.setValue()` method to update the value of an entry.

Comment: Maybe renaming the variable holding the `Map.Entry` to `e`, `me` or `entry` would make the examples a bit clearer, as `m` can imply something that's not true here.